# ERROR: Error 1005: Can't create table 'cat10e.recording' (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to forward engineer my databae that has 7 tables but one is shooting me an error. I don't really know what to do from here because it is setup just like the rest of my tables so I'm unsure what is causing the error and google returns a multitude of varied answers. Album SQL: pastebin.com/A3axVAA5

```
Executing SQL script in server

ERROR: Error 1005: Can't create table 'cat10e.recording' (errno: 150)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cat10e`.`recording` (
 `rec_id` SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  `album_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `rec_duration` TIME NOT NULL,
  `rec_genre` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `rec_cost` DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL,
  `rec_title` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `rec_date` DATE NOT NULL,
  `rec_note` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`rec_id`, `album_id`),
  INDEX `fk_recording_album1_idx` (`album_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_recording_album1`
 FOREIGN KEY (`album_id`)
REFERENCES `cat10e`.`album` (`album_id`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB

SQL script execution finished: statements: 21 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

Comment: can you post the SQL for the `cat10e`.`album` table, please? In fact, did the `cat10e`.`album` table exist at the point that you ran this script?

Comment: @TomMac here is the SQL for album:
http://pastebin.com/A3axVAA5
and yes it done before the recording table

Comment: The types do not match of `album_id`. Use the same

Comment: @carlgoodtoseeyou You need to put that definition **in your question**

Comment: @TomMac If all the necessary details aren't contained in the question, it won't be useful to future visitors.

Comment: @Kermit he asked for it in the comments, so I figure why not just reply to him in the comments. Sorry I'm new here, won't happen again.

Comment: @carlgoodtoseeyou Just update your question with the other table definition so your question can be helpful to future visitors.

Comment: @carlgoodtoseeyou No, not the link. The **actual table definition**. Some people can't access Pastebin and links go bad over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the DDL for the `album` table it looks like the `album_id` column is defined as:

```
`album_id` SMALLINT NOT NULL
```

Whereas the `album_id` column in the `recording` table is defined as:

```
`album_id` INT NOT NULL
```

Try changing the `album_id` column in the `recording` table to this:

```
`album_id` SMALLINT NOT NULL
```

They have to match if you want to set up a FK from `recording`.`album_id` to `album`.`album_id`!

Comment: carlgoodtoseeyou provided a link to it in the OP comments since I asked him politely for it ;-)

Comment: Ahh such a simple error. Thanks for the keen eyes @TomMac.

Comment: Of course it just led to another error, but I'll just ask about it under a new question.